# How to disinguish html/text button content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to distinguish between the following three styles of button:

```
<button>Something</button>

<button><i class="icon-user"></i> Something</button>

<button><i class="icon-user"></i></button>
```

I have tried using `html().length` and `Is('i')` which allows me to distinguish between the first and the others but not sure of the best approach to determine if the content is only the icon or if there is also text.

Comment: `i` is deprecated. What's wrong with adding a CSS class and `font-style: italic`? When you add the class you can also distinguish the cases. The 3rd empty case looks like a job for `display: none;`

Comment: i is just being used as a placholder for a glyph font - fontawesome in this case.

Comment: add 3 different classes to these buttons. that ought to do it

Comment: @Krishna - I cannot add classes or attributes. just want to be able to do it using the markup as shown.

Comment: @Frits - Yes, span may be better. Just following font awesome site convention. Either way, i or span not relevant to question/answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).children().length > 0` will return `true` in case 2 and 3.

`$(this).text().length > 0` will return `true` in case 1 and 2.

Use those in combination.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. My example just changes the button background colour, but obviously you can change that to do whatever you like.

```
// Case 1
$('button:not(:has(i))').css('background', '#00f');

$('button:has(i)').each(function () {
    var btn = $(this);

    if (btn.text().length > 0) {
        // Case 2
        btn.css('background', '#0f0');
    } else {
        // Case 3
        btn.css('background', '#f00');
    }
});
```

Here's a Fiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/SJDJD/

Answer (score 0):

To check if the button has any html element(s):

```
$("button").each(function(i){
    index = i+1;
    htmlElements = $(this).find("*");
    if(htmlElements.length > 0){
        alert("Button no. "+index+" has an html object");
    }
});
```